# fpdf Output('file.pdf','D') download the file but doesn't show it in the browser

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using FPDF class in php to create pdf file in my webpage but it download the pdf but doesn't show it on the browser or create a garbage.

here is my code

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
$pdf =new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output('file.pdf','D');
?>
```

this code download the pdf file but doesn't show the pdf file in the page 
if i change the last line from

```
$pdf->Output('file.pdf','D'); to $pdf->Output('file.pdf','I');
```

it output this

```
%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�r Q�w3T04�30PISp  �Z*�[����(hx����+����(j*�d��7W endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 5 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 6 0 obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.7) /CreationDate (D:20150920120751) >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R >> endobj xref 0 8 0000000000 65535 f 0000000228 00000 n 0000000416 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000315 00000 n 0000000520 00000 n 0000000595 00000 n trailer << /Size 8 /Root 7 0 R /Info 6 0 R >> startxref 644 %%EOF
```

any help

or can you recommend me other method to create pdf file in php

Comment: Looks like a cache issue. Just pass some random get-values to the URL and try again.

Comment: i added exit; after $pdf->output('file.pdf','D'); and it worked for chrome but not firefox

Comment: Are you using the "latest" FPDF version? Could you check if your PHP file is saved with a [BOM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)? If so, remove it! You also can avoid the exit call and simply omit the closing php-tag.

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

```
string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
```

so

```
$pdf->Output('I','file.pdf');
```

should do it.